# easy_install virtualenvwrapper error in CentOS 5.8 64bit

Tags: python, easy-install, virtualenvwrapper

Installed Python 2.6.1 (with /opt prefix), setuptools 0.6c9, and virtualenv onto CentOS 5.8 64bit.(I was mostly following the instructions from here: http://bda.ath.cx/blog/2009/04/08/installing-python-26-in-centos-5-or-rhel5/comment-page-1/#comment-15422)

I got stuck when I tried to install virtualenwrapper and got the following errors:

```
/opt/bin/easy_install virtualenvwrapper
Searching for virtualenvwrapper
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenvwrapper/
Best match: virtualenvwrapper 4.1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=f18f2c612b936583a8ec0f7114b6637e
Processing virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1.tar.gz
Running virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg –dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-oaCjsg
Checking .pth file support in .
/opt/bin/python2.6 -E -c pass
Searching for pbr>=0.5.19
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/
Best match: pbr 0.5.21
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pbr/pbr-0.5.21.tar.gz#md5=1dafd1ef666b9bce4d880170ddc39387
Processing pbr-0.5.21.tar.gz
Running pbr-0.5.21/setup.py -q bdist_egg –dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/temp/easy_install-Prh_Pq/pbr-0.5.21/egg-dist-tmp-PLfFJs

Installed /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/pbr-0.5.21-py2.6.egg
Searching for pip>=1.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 1.4.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=6afbb46aeb48abac658d4df742bff714
Processing pip-1.4.1.tar.gz
Running pip-1.4.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg –dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/temp/easy_install-N07Olv/pip-1.4.1/egg-dist-tmp-cH_0sg
warning: no files found matching ‘*.html’ under directory ‘docs’
warning: no previously-included files matching ‘*.rst’ found under directory ‘docs/_build’
no previously-included directories found matching ‘docs/_build/_sources’

Installed /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/pip-1.4.1-py2.6.egg
/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py:245: UserWarning: Module pbr was already imported from /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/temp/easy_install-Prh_Pq/pbr-0.5.21/pbr/__init__.py, but /tmp/easy_install-gIYCea/virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1/pbr-0.5.21-py2.6.egg is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/opt/bin/easy_install”, line 8, in
load_entry_point(‘setuptools==0.6c9′, ‘console_scripts’, ‘easy_install’)()
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 1671, in main
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 1659, in with_ei_usage
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 1675, in
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py”, line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py”, line 975, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py”, line 995, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 211, in run
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 446, in easy_install
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 476, in install_item
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 655, in install_eggs
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 930, in build_and_install
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py”, line 919, in run_setup
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py”, line 27, in run_setup
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py”, line 63, in run
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py”, line 29, in
File “setup.py”, line 7, in
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py”, line 113, in setup
_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py”, line 223, in __init__
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py”, line 270, in __init__
self.finalize_options()
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py”, line 256, in finalize_options
File “/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py”, line 1913, in load
ImportError: No module named core
```

No idea what's going on. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

it turned out by using a newer version of setuptools solved the problem.